# Как перенести все стили ячеек из xlrd в openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlrd

Есть скрипт, который открывает файл `xls` с помощью `xlrd` и конвертирует его в `xlsx` посредством `openpyxl`. Но есть проблема, которая заключается в форматировании ячеек. Увы, этот скрипт не переносит стили. Как можно реализовать это?

### Скрипт:

```
xlsBook = xlrd.open_workbook_xls(file)
tables = xl.Workbook()

for i in range(0, xlsBook.nsheets):
    xlsSheet = xlsBook.sheet_by_index(i)
    sheet = tables.active if i == 0 else tables.create_sheet()
    sheet.title = xlsSheet.name

    for row in range(0, xlsSheet.nrows):
        for col in range(0, xlsSheet.ncols):
            sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1).value = xlsSheet.cell_value(row, col)
```